# Android button styling looks different on different devices (AOSP and Samsung Galaxy)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am devloping an app which I am testing on the OnePlus 3 and the Samsung Galaxy Tab A. The tablet is a recent addition to my list and all the development until now was on the OnePlus 3.

My problem is that the same button rendors differently on the Galaxy Tablet than on the OnePlus 3.

Previously I had tried the app on the Nexus 9 emulator in Android Studio and it rendored as it should. This makes me feel that Samsung has messed with something which is changing the look of my button.

To put the problem more exactly, the button background fills the entire view on the tablet as is visible in the screenshot. I want to make it like a normal android button.

The code of my button is like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/outputButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="13sp"/>
```

I can get the same look on both of them if I specify a background (btn_default) on the button. But that obviously causes the animations of the button to not work anymore.
According to my understanding, the default style (Widget.AppCompat.Button; which I also tried stating explicitly) should also use the default background (btn_default) but there seems to be some flaw with my understanding of this.

So how do I get the same look on both the devices?

Galaxy Tab A -

[image]
[image]

OnePlus 3 -

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. Not the most clean solution, but it works.

Use this for your button's background drawable. The values that I have mentioned are taken directly from the material design source files. You can tinker with them to change the look of the button.
Most importantly, I had to add the ripple tag to allow the standard animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetBottom="6dp"
       android:insetLeft="4dp"
       android:insetRight="4dp"
       android:insetTop="6dp">
    <ripple
        android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
                <solid android:color="?attr/colorButtonNormal"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="4dp"
                    android:left="8dp"
                    android:right="8dp"
                    android:top="4dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
</inset>
```

I still don't understand why the problem happened in the first place, but this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Mostly it will work , because this `AppCompatButton` subclass of `Button` and will compactible with all the devices.

Comment: It did not work. Exactly the same thing on both the devices.